# jms queue receiver which always run in backgrond

Tags: jms

I want a Java class (jms receiver) which always run in background and check for any message arrive in jms queue.How it can be possible? Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you want is a JMS `MessageListener`.  Create your JMS client resources (e.g. connection/context, session, etc.) like normal and then invoke `setMessageListener` on your consumer passing in your implementation of the `MessageListener` interface.  This is pretty basic JMS stuff so you can find more detailed tutorials online.

Comment: I actually want the class which will implement  MessageListener  will run always instead of manual execution frequently.

Comment: The MessageListener will continue running and receiving messages in the background until it is closed.  The only "manual execution" comes when the MessageListener is first created.  That's the whole point of the MessageListener.

Comment: Thanks. I got it.